# How do I access a column on the new data frame after I do a groupby on it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

Suppose 'X' is a column in the dataframe df1, giving categorical values.

I run a `df2=df1.groupby('X').sum()`

to get a new dataframe df2. When I print df2, I can still see 'X' as a column in it. But somehow I cannot access it using df2['X']. It does not even show up in `df2.columns`.

How can I make 'X' accessible in df2? I guess it has something to do with an index column of a dataframe or as such, but I really need to use 'X' in df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) because first column is called `index`:

```
df2=df1.groupby('X').sum()
print (df2.index)

df2=df1.groupby('X').sum().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df2=df1.groupby('X', as_index=False).sum()
```

If groupby by multiple columns get `MultiIndex`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['patient_id', 'date_of_admission']).sum()
print (df2.index)
```

And also help `as_index=False` parameter or `reset_index()` function.

**Sample**:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2017-01-01'] * 3 + ['2017-01-02'] * 2)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':list('aabba'),
                   'patient_id':[4,5,4,3,3],
                   'A':[7,8,9,1,2,],
                   'date_of_admission':dates})

print (df1)
   A  X date_of_admission  patient_id
0  7  a        2017-01-01           4
1  8  a        2017-01-01           5
2  9  b        2017-01-01           4
3  1  b        2017-01-02           3
4  2  a        2017-01-02           3

df2=df1.groupby('X').sum()
print (df2)
    A  patient_id
X                
a  17          12
b  10           7

print (df2.index)
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object', name='X')

df2=df1.groupby('X').sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
   X   A  patient_id
0  a  17          12
1  b  10           7

df2=df1.groupby('X', as_index=False).sum()
print (df2)
   X   A  patient_id
0  a  17          12
1  b  10           7
```

---

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['patient_id', 'date_of_admission']).sum()
print (df2)
                               A
patient_id date_of_admission    
3          2017-01-02          3
4          2017-01-01         16
5          2017-01-01          8

print (df2.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[3, 4, 5], [2017-01-01 00:00:00, 2017-01-02 00:00:00]],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 0]],
           names=['patient_id', 'date_of_admission'])

df2 = df1.groupby(['patient_id', 'date_of_admission']).sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
   patient_id date_of_admission   A
0           3        2017-01-02   3
1           4        2017-01-01  16
2           5        2017-01-01   8

df2 = df1.groupby(['patient_id', 'date_of_admission'], as_index=False).sum()
print (df2)
   patient_id date_of_admission   A
0           3        2017-01-02   3
1           4        2017-01-01  16
2           5        2017-01-01   8
```

*Notice*: Column `date_of_admission` was omited in first sample and column `X` in second sample, because [automatic exclusion of nuisance columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns).